# Using opponent's first sequence spaces

Tags: sequence

My question is for the case of two teams where two sequences are needed to win the game. Say team Blue built a sequence and team Green hasn't.

The rules say:

> If you are playing the game which requires two SEQUENCES to win, you may use any one of the spaces from your first SEQUENCE as part of your second.

So does this mean team Blue can place chips over the first sequence chips, but team Green CANNOT place chips over team Blue's first sequence. Right?

Comment: You can never "place chips *over*" other chips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, you cannot use your opponent's sequence space.

But what it also mean is that a player/team can use a chip (of their own) already in play as part of a SEQUENCE, to complete another SEQUENCE. So if you e.g. have a horizontal SEQUENCE you can use any of these chips to complete e.g. a vertical SEQUENCE.

So no one can place a chip on top of another chip that has already been placed on the board.

> Set-Up
>   ... Once a marker chip has been played, it cannot be removed by an opponent except when using a one-eyed Jack as explained below...

And by the normal rules you cannot remove chips from a already completed SEQUENCE.

> The Jacks
>   ... You cannot remove a marker chip that is already part of a completed SEQUENCE. 
>   Once a SEQUENCE is achieved by a player or a team, it cannot be broken...

[SEQUENCE Rules](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53ec790ae4b0396cbd14d8a1/t/5ad4158f352f53c87a470cb6/1523848592053/sequence-board-game-rules.pdf)